# How is the output of this expression 43?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

I am learning C language and now I am confused with the output of the below snippet.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int p = 20;
    printf("%d\n",++p + p++);
    return 0;
}
```

[`Online Fiddle`](https://ideone.com/JDKvbP)

How is the output of this `43`?

As far as I have understood, it should be evaluating as below:

- `++p` makes it 21.
- `p++`, makes it 22 but will be `21` during addition since it is post-increment.

So the expected output should be `21 + 21 = 42`. Isn't it?

Comment: There is one point you have not understood, and that is: when there are too many things going on in a single expression — in this case, when there are two separate attempts to update the value of `p` — everything falls apart.  There is no rule to say which happens first, so anything can happen.  (And in particular, there is no rule that says things happen left-to-right, or anything like that.)

Comment: Evaluating this code at tio.run you'll find that the clang and tcc compilers produce 42, while GCC produces 43.

Comment: Giga-dupe, covered by the FAQ:(